# Error persisting stof doctrine extension uploadble. Symfony 2.3

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine-uploadable

This is my controller - right from documentation

```
<?php

namespace Votes\VotesBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use Votes\VotesBundle\Entity\File as File;

class FileController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * @Template()
     */
    public function newAction()
    {
        $file = new File();
        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($file)
            ->add('name')
            ->add('file','file')
            ->getForm()
        ;

        if ($this->getRequest()->getMethod() === 'POST') {
            $form->bind($this->getRequest());

            if ($form->isValid()) {
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

                $em->persist($file);

                $uploadableManager = $this->get('stof_doctrine_extensions.uploadable.manager');

                // Here, "getMyFile" returns the "UploadedFile" instance that the form bound in your $myFile property
                $uploadableManager->markEntityToUpload($file, $file->getFile());

                $em->flush();

                $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('/file/new'));
            }
        }

        return array('form' => $form->createView());

    }

}
```

Here's my File entity

```
<?php
se Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
/**
 * File
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="files")
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @Gedmo\Uploadable( allowOverwrite=true, appendNumber=true, filenameGenerator="SHA1")
 */
class File
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="path", type="string")
     * @Gedmo\UploadableFilePath
     */
    private $path;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string")
     * @Gedmo\UploadableFileName
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="mime_type", type="string")
     * @Gedmo\UploadableFileMimeType
     */
    private $mimeType;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="size", type="decimal")
     * @Gedmo\UploadableFileSize
     */
    private $size;

    private $file;

    public function setFile($file)
    {
        $this->file = $file;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getFile()
    {
        return $this->file;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set path
     *
     * @param string $path
     * @return File
     */
    public function setPath($path)
    {
        $this->path = $path;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get path
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPath()
    {
        return $this->path;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return File
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set mimeType
     *
     * @param string $mimeType
     * @return File
     */
    public function setMimeType($mimeType)
    {
        $this->mimeType = $mimeType;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get mimeType
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getMimeType()
    {
        return $this->mimeType;
    }

    /**
     * Set size
     *
     * @param string $size
     * @return File
     */
    public function setSize($size)
    {
        $this->size = $size;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get size
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSize()
    {
        return $this->size;
    }
}
```

I get this error when submit form:

An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO files (path, name, mime_type, size) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)' with params [null, "asdasdasd", null, null]:

### SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'path' cannot be null

If I'm correct - the uploadable extension - must fill my File entity with
correct data in events? I'm right?

Comment: Are you sending the value `path`. Can you able to return the value of `path` ?

Comment: Dont really understand what are you mean. Can you bee more specific?  I can do it of corse. But where the sence?

Comment: I don't know symfony, But i can guess from the error, it is clear that you there are no values for path, mime_type, size. I am just making sure that, Can you able to return or print the values before the you do the save action ?

Comment: That's is a problem - this values must be filled in prePersist event from $_FILES array automaticaly

Comment: Is it possible to `var_dump` or `print_r` the $_FILES Array ?

Comment: Have you set `stof_doctrine_extensions:orm:default:uploadable` to `true` in the `app/config/config.yml`? (`default` being the default, your entity manager may be different)

Comment: Ou eah!!! ))) break point in onFlush now work !!!! Thanks! I really dont understand from docs that need truefy all needed extension (((